# engine yard No application found matching remotes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, engineyard

I'm trying to deploy my application to production on my laptop but i keep getting a

```
No application found matching remotes:
    git@github.com:this_is_the_old_github_remote/Application.git
```

so this used to be the old remote but it was recently changed

so this makes sense but how do I fix this issue and tell it to go to the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to work around this issue.

1. Update the repository's config to have the proper URL for your remote branch.
2. Tell the ey cli tool which application and environment you are trying to deploy to.

The first method is probably better so you do not have to worry about this in the future.

To update your repository configuration you simply need to run `git remote set-url origin https://url.to/new/repo/Applicatoin.git`

Once the repository in your git configuration and the Engine Yard dashboard match, you should be able to deploy normally.

To work around this issue via the Engine Yard CLI utility, you will need to run `ey deploy --app=<Application Name> --environment=<Environment Name>`.

Please keep in mind, regardless of which method above you use to work around this issue, Engine Yard's automation will pull the application from the repository you configured via the dashboard.

Updating the remote on your git configuration does **not** update Engine Yard's configuration.

If your local copy of the repository has changes that have not been pushed to the remote repository configured at Engine Yard, the changes will not propagate to your instances.

If you continue to run into any issues deploying, please feel free to contact us via http://support.cloud.engineyard.com or in IRC on irc.freenode.net in #EngineYard.